# "wGeT" keyword in $_POST

Tags: php, http, browser

I am developing a small application where an admin can insert bulk discount voucher codes in the back-end. In the front-end, site visitors can get those codes, one by one. To insert voucher codes in the backend, I am providing the admin a Textarea where he can insert them all at once. Everything was working fine, until I got a unique voucher code **"XXXXXX-XXX-XXX-wGeT"**.

I have a simple HTML form, which is submitted using the POST method. On submitting this voucher code, the browser sends me a "501-Method not implemented" error in the response. The problem is with the "wGet" keyword in the code. I know wget is a linux command, but here I am sending it as a text in POST. Server just sending me 501 error. I googled a lot, but didn't have any luck. How do I escape this "wGeT" keyword, before form submit?

edit:

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wget Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frmCodes" method="POST">
            <textarea name="voucher_codes"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is plain text. It doesn't need escaping. You need to find out what is causing the error (it is probably some paranoid security filter) and fix it there instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: Can you show some more code, plus explain what server you are on – this sounds unlikely to be as simple as it sounds, and I suspect the wget thing is just a coincidence. Try it with `wTeG` at the end, and `less` as well, to verify if it is only wget.

Comment: Might or might not be a mod_security error.

Comment: @RichBradshaw: I am using Apache/2.2.0 (Fedora) server. On my local windows machine its working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think mario's comment is right, it's probably mod_security.

default behaviour will be scanning POST data ( see /etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.conf )

```
SecFilterScanPOST On
```

with wget blocked

```
# WEB-ATTACKS wget command attempt
SecFilter "wget\x20"
```

comment out this SecFilter by preceding it with # (or set SecFilterScanPOST to Off) and restart apache to see if it solves it.

or use a [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file in the corresponding directory containing:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
# Turn the filtering engine On or Off or DynamicOnly for cgi/php/etc
SecFilterEngine On

# Should mod_security inspect POST payloads
SecFilterScanPOST Off

# this rule allows wget but logs it so you can verify it if necessary
SecFilter "wget\x20" "log,pass"
</ifModule>
```

I put both options in so you can play with it somewhat, it's probably possible to be more site specific but you'll need to read up a bit on [mod_security rules](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/index.html)

slight edit: added a wget allowing but logging rule to [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess), this would allow you to put SecFilterScanPOST to On

Comment: I am on shared hosting so I don't think I could configure this modsecurity.conf file. Need to find any other alternative.

Comment: you can put in a .htaccess file, I'll adapt my post to show it